# Html Fileinput with using the "Photo Library" option does not work on IOS

Tags: html, ios, angular, typescript, input

I have an Angular PWA which should enable an user to upload an image to an AWS S3 Bucket.
It works on Windows and Android in any browser, but on IOS neither in Firefox and Chrome nor in Safari, when using the "Photo Library".

The option "Take Photo or Video" actually works without problems, but when using the "Photo Library" option, it lets me choose an Image but nothing happens after selection. Debugging with the mobile Chrome console suggest that the processFile($event) function is not even called, but I cant find out why.

Because of design choices the input´s style is "display: none" and I use another button to open it, but since it opens would let me upload a new photo and lets me actually choose images I would not think that this is the issue.

HTML:

```
  <input #imageInput type="file" accept="image/*, video/*" (change)="processFile($event)"/>
  <button (click)="imageInput.click()">
```

Typescript:

```
async processFile($event) {

let input = $event.target;
this.reset();
this.loadingDialogRef = this.matDialog.open(PopupComponent, {data: {type: popupType.LOADING}});

this.files = input.files;
console.log(this.files);
  let i = input.files.length;
  this.fileNumber = i;

  if(i > this.limit){
    alert("Maximum von " + this.limit + " Bildern erlaubt.")
    this.reset();
    return;
  }

try{
  let res = await Promise.all([].map.call( this.files, (file) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise  (function( resolve, reject) {
          
          reader.onload  = (event:any) => {
         
          resolve({encoded: event.target.result, file});
    
          };

          if(  file.size > 2512 * 10000){
            alert("Datei: " + file.name + " ist größer als die erlaubte größe von 25mb");   
            this.reset();
            reject();
            
          } 
        else if( file.size < 1000){
          alert("Datei: " + file.name + " ist kleiner als die mindest größe von 1kb");
          this.reset();
          reject();

        } else { 
          console.log("here");
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       }
      });
   
  })).then((results) => {
    console.log(this.imageType);
    var imageType = this.imageType;
    results.forEach((result: any) => {
      
      let id = uuid();
      
      this.cdnService.uploadImage(result.encoded, id, imageType ).subscribe(res =>{
        this.delay(2400).then(() =>{
          result.id = id;
          this.imagelist.push(result);
          this.imageURLs.push(res.objectURL)
          })
      });
    });
    return results;
  }); 
  console.log(res);
  return res;
} catch(err){
  this.reset();
}
}

reset(){
  this.imagelist = [];
  this.imageURLs = [];
  this.files = [];
  this.fileNumber = 0;
    if(this.loadingDialogRef){
      this.loadingDialogRef.close();
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I just found out that it behaves exactly the same on MacOS.

Comment: This looks incorrect to me: $event.srcElement - I think this should be event.target?

Comment: Changed it to let input = $event.target; Change had no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So after a hilariously long session of trial and error I found out that the "cause" actually layed a layer upwards. For design reasons I called the upload after a click on an object from the parent component.

In the parent component, the child in which the file-input is, was referenced with a @ViewChild. After the (click) on the parent component, it called a method from the child, which caused a click on the file-input programmatically.

For some reason, this caused that all events from the file-input got not triggered on iOS aswell as MacOS Safari.